# RegEx в JS: как заменить множественные паттерны множественными значениями?

Tags: javascript, html

Я хочу перевести HTML-разметку в свою собственную систему разметки через JS.
Проблема такова, что приходится на каждый тег проходиться отдельным .replaceAll(). На текущий момент у меня уже 5 таких проходов, и чем дальше в лес, тем больше дров, что не очень хорошо сказывается на производительности, да и выглядит колхозно.

```
const contentBody = document.getElementById("workArea").innerHTML;
return contentBody
  .replaceAll(/<b>(.+?)<\/b>|<strong>(.+?)<\/strong>/g, "**$1**")
  .replaceAll(/<i>(.+?)<\/i>|<em>(.+?)<\/em>/g, "*$1*")
  .replaceAll(/<div>(.+?)<\/div>/g, "\\$1\\")
  .replaceAll(/<li>(.+?)<\/li>/gm, "-$1\n")
  .replaceAll(/<ul>|<\/ul>/g, "");
```

Есть ли вариант сделать что-то на подобии такого?

```
let regexes = [
    /<b>(.+?)<\/b>|<strong>(.+?)<\/strong>/g,
    /<i>(.+?)<\/i>|<em>(.+?)<\/em>/g,
    /<div>(.+?)<\/div>/g,
    /<li>(.+?)<\/li>/gm,
    /<ul>|<\/ul>/g
];

let replacements = [
    "**$1**",
    "*$1*",
    "\\$1\\",
    "-$1\n",
    ""
];
return contentBody.replaceAll(regexes, replacements);
```

, где за ***один*** проход регулярное выражение заменит в тексте все regex[0] на replacements[0], все regex[1] на replacements[1], все regex[2] на replacements[2] и т.д.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285472/multiple-regex-replace) есть ответ на ваш вопрос. Если коротко, то нет готовой функции, которая подобные замены делала бы. По этому или циклом, или по ссылке можете посмотреть еще один способ.

Comment: Добавь пример входного html, желательно с примерами всех тегов, и результат, который хочешь получить